# Dynamically selecting external credentials with Named Credentials

Tags: apex, integration, customsetting, namedcredentials, externalcredentials

We have a button that integrates with an external system using Named Credentials. We are using per-user authentication here and every user authenticates themselves with their external system username and password beforehand itself. Now the requirement is that certain salesforce users could have multiple credentials in the external system and they should be allowed to choose their credentials while clicking the button. Additionally, the users who have single credentials should bypass this step and be able to directly connect.
[image: requiredApproach]

My plan was to have additional named credentials created and assign those to required users alone and query them in a screen flow. I am stuck with this as even though I was able to query the named credentials for admins, this is getting restricted for other profiles.

Is this a feasible approach or do we have a better design for these?

Comment: Adding a little bit to the background, this requirement is because of the limitation in the external system to provide access for a single user to multiple entities/system records. So they have created different users for same person to view each entity records. I feel this is something that need to be handled by the external system and not at salesforce>

Comment: Multiple accounts is a common yet very unfortunate "solution" to the access control/data security problem Out of the box, Named/External Cred isn't going to handle this, e.g. you can't attach multiple per-user principals to EC. (In SF architecture this doesn't make sense). When we did something similar for some of our customers, we rolled our own custom framework for this entire thing.